# Нетипизированный связной список

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как бы я мог получить значение `value` из своей структуры `Val`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct Val {
    T value;
};

struct node{
    void* data;
    node* Next;
};


int main() {
   node a{};
   node b{};

   Val<int> c = {41};
   Val<string> d = {"gfdsa"};

   a.data = &c;
   b.data = &d;
   a.Next = &b;

   cout << (a.Next->data);
}
```

Comment: Тип данных придется хранить. Если типов немного (а памяти очень мало), то его можно упаковать в указатель (скорее всего это будет машинозависимое решение)

Answer (score 0):

Это плохой подход. Допустим вы написали так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

enum NodeType {String, Int};

struct NodeBase {
    NodeType type;
    NodeBase* next;
};

template <typename T>
struct Node: NodeBase {
    std::unique_ptr<T> data;
};


int main() {
   Node<int> a{};
   a.data = std::make_unique<int>(41);
   a.type = NodeType::Int;

   Node<std::string> b{};
   b.data = std::make_unique<std::string>("qwerty");
   b.type = NodeType::String;
   a.next = &b;

   ...
}
```

Вам КАЖДЫЙ раз при работе со структурой придётся писать что-то наподобие:

```
switch(a.next->type) {
       case NodeType::Int: {
           Node<int>* nodeInt = dynamic_cast<Node<int>*>(a.next);
           DoSomethingWithInt(*(nodeInt->data));
           break;
       }
       case NodeType::String: {
           Node<std::string>* nodeString = dynamic_cast<Node<std::string>*>(a.next);
           DoSomethingWithString(*(nodeString->data));
           break;
       }
   }
```

А при добавлении нового типа в список вы просто умрёте в поисках всех таких switсh по всему коду.

Поэтому стоит совсем разные объекты хранить отдельно, а похожие наследовать от общей базы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>

void DoSomethingWithInt(int data) {
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}

void DoSomethingWithString(const std::string& data) {
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
}

class NodeValueBase {
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
    virtual void SetData(int value) = 0;
    virtual ~NodeValueBase() = default;
};

class NodeValueInt: public virtual NodeValueBase {
public:
    NodeValueInt(int value): data(value) {}; 
    virtual void DoSomething() override {
        DoSomethingWithInt(data);
    }
    virtual void SetData(int value) override {
        data = value;
    }
    int data;
};

class NodeValueString: public virtual NodeValueBase {
public:
    NodeValueString(const std::string& value): data(value) {};
    virtual void DoSomething() override {
        DoSomethingWithString(data);
    }
    virtual void SetData(int value) override {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << value;
        data = ss.str();
    }
    std::string data;
};

template <typename T>
struct Node {
    std::unique_ptr<T> data;
    Node* next;
};

template<typename D, typename B>
std::unique_ptr<D> static_cast_ptr(std::unique_ptr<B>&& base)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<D>(static_cast<D*>(base.release()));
}

int main() {
   Node<NodeValueBase> a{};
   a.data = static_cast_ptr<NodeValueBase, NodeValueInt>(
       std::make_unique<NodeValueInt>(41));

   Node<NodeValueBase> b{};
   b.data = static_cast_ptr<NodeValueBase, NodeValueString>(
       std::make_unique<NodeValueString>("qwerty"));
   a.next = &b;

   a.next->data->DoSomething();
   a.next->data->SetData(123);
   a.next->data->DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: направление мысли правильное, а реализация так себе: делать шаблоном `Node` нет особого смысла, а вот сами реализации `NodeValue` было бы сделать таковыми вполне логично... и да, `SetData()` в базовом классе тоже выглядит несуразно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer `SetData` в базовом классе чисто для примера. `Node` шаблонный, чтобы для хранения других классов с другим интерфейсом не нужно было переписывать заново всю структуру. Как вы представляете шаблонными `NodeValue` я не представляю. В том то и суть, что в них для каждого из типов выновятся особенности реализации.

Comment: @[как-то так](http://paste.debian.net/1092852/), в то то и дело, что особенностей реализации в них практически нет, а всё что есть можно специализировать в шаблонах...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Разные NodeValue можут быть совершенно произвольными классами. Главное наследовать общий интерфейс (при этом не обязательно абстрактный) . А дальше, шаблоны, они, наследники какого-то другого интерфейса, совершенно не важно. Это уже нужно смотреть на конкретные типы, конкретные методы. Там может быть что-то сильно сложнее int и string и сильно сложнее вывода. Повторюсь, это каркас, каркас не предполагает, NodeValue шаблоны, но и не запрещает этого.

Answer (score -1):

Перед тем как "разыменовать" указатель на void, нужно сначала привести тип.

```
cout << ((Val<string>*)a.Next->data)->value << endl;
```

И добавь в начале `#include<string>`

Comment: Это если я знаю тип, но что мне делать, если я к примеру заполняю список разными типами данных, и не знаю какой тип у текущей ноды?

Comment: @DanilTolmachev По-другому ты никак не получишь то, что лежит в твоем указателе :(  Есть паттерн - абстрактная фабрика, посмотри в строну него.

Comment: @DanilTolmachev, АФ тут ничем не поможет... С++ — это язык со статической типизацией и тип результата каждого выражения должен быть известен на этапе компиляции... так что то что ты хочешь принципиально невозможно... как вариант можно, например, добавить виртуальную функцию `toString()` или перегрузку `operator<<` в базовый класс `Val`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а `std::variant`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, честно сказать, я его мало щупал пока, но он вряд ли здесь чем-то поможет: это только надстройка над обычным C-шным `union`'ом, а не полноценный variant-тип... так что по идей ему нужна нужна будет такая же обёртка, чтобы использовать его так как хочет OP...